# Portaudio on Raspberry Pi, cannot find device for input stream

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, real-time, audio-streaming, portaudio

I'm new for Portaudio, and I install it on Raspberry Pi with a device called Matrix Creator. The Matrix Creator connects the Pi using all the GPIO pins, and it has 8 microphones on that.

I want to use Portaudio to realize real-time audio streaming (play the sound while it recording, or play whatever it collected by the mics simultaneously).

According to the [Portaudio website](http://web.mit.edu/carrien/Public/speechlab/marc_code/ADAPT_VC/rtaudio/doc/html/classRtAudio.html), it says we have to know the device Id for both inputStream and outputStream. And I used the function ***Pa_GetDeviceCount*** to check what can the Pi detects, the code shows below:

```
  int numDevices = Pa_GetDeviceCount();
  cout<<"Device num: "<<numDevices<<endl;
  const PaDeviceInfo * deviceInfo;
  for(int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++){ 
      deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(i);
      cout<<"Device info of "<<i<<"is :"<<deviceInfo;}
```

The result I got:

```
Device num: -10000
```

***Question 1***

Is there any way I can get the device info for my Matrix's mics?

***Question 2***

Since I cannot get the input device Id, and I still want to use buffers to pass the data received from mics as my inputStream, (I can put all the signal received by mics into a 2D buffer, [code](https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-hal/blob/master/demos/micarray_recorder_direct.cpp)), what can I do to realize ***real-time audio collecting and playing***?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that specific piece of hardware, it seems that it's not supposed to act as a seperate audio interface (in your typical way like an external sound card). This is why portaudio won't specifically recognize it.

If you look at the code that you linked, and the MATRIX documentation, the whole software runs on top of an abstraction layer (the [HAL](https://matrix-io.github.io/matrix-documentation/)). This lets you call into kernel modules using C++ to read the values from the device. So it is intended that you access the audio inputs from the hardware, through the HAL kernel modules in C++ (or a higher level interface if you want to use a different language / probably an easier setup with [MATRIX Core](https://matrix-io.github.io/matrix-documentation/matrix-core/overview/)).

This is exactly the [code you linked](https://github.com/matrix-io/matrix-creator-hal/blob/master/demos/micarray_recorder_direct.cpp); accessing the microphone inputs through the kernel modules in C++!

So:

**Question 1 - Is there any way I can get the device info for my Matrix's mics?**

I would be suprised if you could access each mic's device info individually UNLESS the HAL supports this (although after looking I haven't seen anything in the documentation).

**Question 2 - Since I cannot get the input device Id, and I still want to use buffers to pass the data received from mics as my inputStream, (I can put all the signal received by mics into a 2D buffer, code), what can I do to realize real-time audio collecting and playing?**

Setting up the audio output for portaudio is a very commonly done task so I'm sure you will find many examples online on how to do it. For starters [this source code](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__sine_8c_source.html) is included in the portaudio download, for playing floating point data (a sine wave) through the portaudio selected output.

However, for real-time the general technique is to [write a callback function](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html) that when the audio output device is ready for more audio, it will run the callback function to return the next buffer of audio. There are more examples of this in the portaudio examples folder (i.e. the [paex_fuzz.c](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/pa__fuzz_8c_source.html) program).

In this callback function, you can then do any DSP processing and adjust the signal as you like.

**PLEASE NOTE:**
The portaudio callback function can be called at an interrupt level and will be searching for new input blocks very rapidly so I am not sure how viable sending audio to portaudio like this is (without extreme buffering). But have not seen another way supported by HAL.

I am not sure what you intend to do with instantaneous playback (other than realtime audio through beamforming so you could hear what Alexa/Google Home hears?) and I believe this device is not intended for this purpose, but I hope this could help!

Comment: the micarray_recorder_direct.cpp is the file I'm trying to use for getting the audio signal. And I wish to use the buffer which fed by "mics.read()". Since I want to have a infinite real-time streaming, where should I put the buffer? (Inside main function and pass the buffer to callback? or read mics inside the callback function?) In the example "paex_sine.c" under portaudio, it seems like they generate data in main and pass the data inside callback, and the callback function only deals with how to pass left and right signal.